# Refactoring thunk slices to RTK-Query causing top-level API calls invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm working on an app using react / redux / redux-toolkit.

Until now, I was using `createAsyncThunk` to wrap API calls, but for more convenience I decided to use RTK-Query.

It works fine in most cases. However, there's a situation in which I'm unable to make it work. This is when I want the API call to be done directly at the app startup, in the `index.js` file, as follows :

**Working version :**

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from "react-redux";

import App from './App';
import store from './store';
import {fetchUserInfo} from "./features/user";

store.dispatch(fetchUserInfo());

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here, the `store.dispatch(fetchUserInfo());` is placed here so that `store.user.info` will be available in any subsequent component.

The definition of the `fetchUserInfo()` is made here :

`features/user.js`

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {apiCall} from "./utils";

export const fetchUserInfo = createAsyncThunk(
    'user/info',
    async (thunkAPI) => {
        const res = await apiCall('https://my.api/userinfo').json();
        return res;
    });


export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState: { info: '' },
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
        .addCase(fetchUserInfo.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.info = action.payload;
        })
    },
});

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

What I would like to do is replace this slice by something like that :

**Errored Version :**

`api/user.js`

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

const rawBaseQuery = (baseUrl) => fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl,
    prepareHeaders: (headers, {getState}) => {
        headers.set('Authorization', '*******');
        return headers
    }
});

export const baseQuery = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
    const baseUrl = api.getState().api.root; // 'https://my.api'
    return rawBaseQuery(baseUrl)(args, api, extraOptions);
};

export const userApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'user',
    baseQuery: baseQuery,
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getUserInfo: builder.query({
            query: () => `/userinfo`
        }),
    }),
});
    
export const {
    useGetUserInfoQuery
} = userApi;
```

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from "react-redux";

import App from './App';
import store from './store';
import {useGetUserInfoQuery} from "./api/user";

store.dispatch(useGetUserInfoQuery());

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But, I can not call `useGetUserInfoQuery()` in `ìndex.js`. The following error occurs :

`React Hook use query cannot be called at the top level.`

I also tried to call `useGetUserInfoQuery()` without dispatch but the same error occurs.

How should I proceed? Thanks!

Comment: It's a hook - it is meant to be called within your `App` component.

Comment: I know, but the point of my question is precisely how can I use RTK queries outside a component, without using hooks necessarily.

Comment: And that is covered in the documentation in a chapter called [Usage Without React Hooks](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/usage-without-react-hooks) - but if your real use really looks like in your example above, you should really just put it into your `App` component.